# TYPO3: Using ###PAGE_TSCONFIG_ID### with addRecord in TCA

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

The problem at hand has to do with the TCA and its `addRecord` option, which should save new records to a specific pid configured by `###PAGE_TSCONFIG_ID###`. (TYPO3 8.7.24, php 7.2)

The `websites` extension has a `tx_rwfm_domain_model_websitecategory` and a `tx_rwfm_domain_model_website` table, related via a m:m table. The idea is to create website categories and then collect websites, which are assigned to a category. In the BE, the categories (pid=24) as well as the websites (pid=12) have their own folder in the site tree. `websitecategory` has a multiSelectField to easily select websites and assign them to the category in question. And also "website" has a multiSelectField for categories to easily assign a website to multiple categories.

So far everything is working fine.

Now I bump into this scenario:

- I want to add websites to the categories, so I open the `websitecategory` folder page in list view.
- I now realise that the website I want to add has not yet been created.
- Instead of closing the `websitecategory` page, I click on "addRecord" next the multiSelectField of `websites` (m:m connection)
- A new window opens to create the new website, "save and close" brings me back to the websitecategory page, where I can see that the new website was added to the selection list.

The point is: The new website has to be created in its own folder page (pid=12) and NOT on the websitecategory page (pid=24). To do so, there is the property `###PAGE_TSCONFIG_ID###`, which I try to configure like this:

```
// TCA of websitecategory

return [
  [...],
  'columns' => [
    'websites' => [
      'config' => [
        'type' => 'select',
        'renderType' => 'selectMultipleSideBySide',
        'enableMultiSelectFilterTextfield' => true,
        'foreign_table' => 'tx_rwfm_domain_model_website',
        'foreign_table_where' => 'AND tx_rwfm_domain_model_website.sys_language_uid IN (-1,0) ORDER BY tx_rwfm_domain_model_website.title ASC',
        'MM' => 'tx_rwfm_domain_model_website_websitecategory_mm',
        'MM_opposite_field' => 'categories',
        'fieldControl' => [
          'editPopup' => [...],
          'addRecord' => [
            'disabled' => false,
            'options' => [
              'setValue' => 'prepend',
              'title' => 'Create a new website record',
              'table' => 'tx_rwfm_domain_model_website',
              'pid' => '###PAGE_TSCONFIG_ID###',
            ],
          ],
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [...]
]
```

Following the documentation `https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TSconfigReference/8.7/PageTsconfig/TCEform/Index.html?highlight=page_tsconfig_id` I add this to my page TSconfig:

```
// TSconfig

TCEFORM {
    tx_rwfm_domain_model_website {
        pid.PAGE_TSCONFIG_ID = 12
    }
    tx_rwfm_domain_model_websitecategory {
        pid.PAGE_TSCONFIG_ID = 28
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. Instead, TYPO3 tries to add it to `[root_level] 0, where the table is not allowed`.
However, if I replace `###PAGE_TSCONFIG_ID###` in `TCA` -> `addRecord` with the hard-coded value of the pid, `12`, the website is indeed saved on the proper page folder with pid 12.

How do I have to configue TSconfig to make the saving process work propertly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `pid` as a table reference before the constant `PAGE_TSCONFIG_ID` is most likely the wrong field you want to address. So this:

```
TCEFORM {
    tx_rwfm_domain_model_website {
        pid.PAGE_TSCONFIG_ID = 12
    }
    tx_rwfm_domain_model_websitecategory {
        pid.PAGE_TSCONFIG_ID = 28
    }
}
```

should become this:

```
TCEFORM {
    tx_rwfm_domain_model_website {
        [field_of_related_table].PAGE_TSCONFIG_ID = 12
    }
    tx_rwfm_domain_model_websitecategory {
        [field_of_related_table].PAGE_TSCONFIG_ID = 28
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as far as I read the source code, this only applies to values defined in `foreign_table_where`.

Comment: Not quite, the docu can be found here: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/8.7/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Select.html?highlight=page_tsconfig_id#addrecord

Comment: Looking at the same problem right now; funny enough, under TYPO3 V9 ###PAGE_TSCONFIG_ID### is not mentioned in the documentation any more:

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/master/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Group.html#columns-group-properties-fieldcontrol

Answer (score 0):

After fooling around quite some time (actually years!), it finally has become clear to me, that the field you need to assign the `PID_TSCONFIG_ID` to has to be the one, that acts as the pivot to the m:m relation. Or: the opposite field. The even more confusing thing about that is, that, by definition, the opposite field must only be defined on one side of the relationship. So for the "other side" you need to look at the related table's name and use that one.

In the above example that would mean, that `categories` has to be used instead of `pid`:

```
// TSconfig

TCEFORM {
  tx_rwfm_domain_model_website {
    categories.PAGE_TSCONFIG_ID = 12
  }
  tx_rwfm_domain_model_websitecategory {
    websites.PAGE_TSCONFIG_ID = 28
  }
}
```

That way, records get saved to their given page ids. Thanks, TYPO3, for providing such a mysterious documentation on that topic! :-( 
Will try to improve the docu in that aspect ASAP.